# Получения номера телефона (телеграм) пользователя с сайта

Tags: javascript, php, telegram-bot

Делаю авторизацию на сайте 1с битрикс с помощью телеграм. Использую их виджет "Telegram Login Widget". После авторизации с помощью виджета можно получить следующие данные:

```
id – уникальный идентификатор пользователя в Telegram
first_name, last_name – фамилия и имя из профиля пользователя
username – уникальное имя из профиля
photo_url – ссылка на аватарку пользователя в виде https://t.me/i/.../user.jpg
auth_date – дата авторазации
hash – HMAC-подпись ответа на основе секретного токена бота
```

Но в данном списке нету **phone_number, возможно ли его как-то получить, с помощью api например?**

Пробовал следующие варианты

```
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?7" data-telegram-login="name_bot" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)"></script>
<?php
$botToken = 'token';
$userId = $_GET['id'];
echo '$userId - ' . $userId;
$apiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/setwebhook?url=https://test.ru/testTelegramAuth/auth.php";
$method = "getUser";
$params = [
    'user_id' => $userId
];

$queryUrl = $apiUrl . '/' . $method . '?' . http_build_query($params);
$response = file_get_contents($queryUrl);
$data = json_decode($response, true);

if ($data['ok']) {
    $user = $data['result'];
    $phoneNumber = $user['phone_number'];

    // Обработка номера телефона по необходимости
    echo 'Номер телефона: ' . $phoneNumber;
} else {
    echo 'Ошибка получения информации о пользователе';
}
?>

<script>
    function onTelegramAuth(user) {
        let phoneNumber = user.phone_number;
        // Обработка номера телефона по необходимости
        console.log('Номер телефона: ' + phoneNumber);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: а каким образом вы сюда хуки бота приплели вообще? Где вы нашли метод `getUser`, который пытаетесь использовать? И пытались ли вы понять, что там у вас в `$queryUrl` формируется перед вызовом?

Comment: @teran, Решил попробовать почему бы и нет. Конечно пытался `$queryUrl = {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}` , в `$response = file_get_contents($queryUrl);` , прилетает bool(false), насколько я понимаю функция не может прочитать полученные данные. Так же пробовал передавать параметр `data-request-phone="true"`, но насколько я понимаю необходимо подтверждение пользователем отправки номера телефона непосредственно через бота

Answer (score 0):

Можно указать параметр request_contact=true для кнопки https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton, тогда будет передан номер

Comment: я пробовал указывать параметр data-request-phone="true", но все равно прилетает undefined. Насколько я понимаю необходимо запросить разрешение на отправку номера телефона через самого бота